# Problema com composer ao enviar para um servidor

Tags: php, mysql, composer

Eu estou usando o composer para criar um site em php OO, porém, ao enviar os arquivos do site para o servidor (que no caso estou usando o serviço gratuito do atwebpages para testes externos), o site simplesmente não funciona, ao tentar se conectar com o mysql ele dá esse error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /srv/disk5/2182077/www/indieworld.atwebpages.com/Indie/Database/Connection.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /srv/disk5/2182077/www/indieworld.atwebpages.com/Indie/Database/Connection.php(18): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=fdb1...', '2182077_indie', 'indieWorld1') #1 /srv/disk5/2182077/www/indieworld.atwebpages.com/Indie/Database/IndieModel.php(19): Indie\Database\Connection->connection() #2 /srv/disk5/2182077/www/indieworld.atwebpages.com/server.php(294): Indie\Database\IndieModel->__construct() #3 /srv/disk5/2182077/www/indieworld.atwebpages.com/server.php(21): login('testando@teste....', '1234') #4 {main} thrown in /srv/disk5/2182077/www/indieworld.atwebpages.com/Indie/Database/Connection.php on line 18
```

Nessa linha 18 que ele está dando o error tem:

```
$pdo = new PDO($this->iniData['driver'].':host='.$this->iniData['host'].';dbname='.$this->iniData['database'], $this->iniData['username'], $this->iniData['password']);
```

Eu preciso instalar o composer via comando dentro do servidor para ele funcionar? Se sim, como faço isso?
Preciso muito resolver esse problema.

Comment: O diretório `vendor` foi enviado junto com a aplicação?

Comment: sim, eu instalei o composer pelo cmd na minha máquina local e simplesmente copiei todos os arquivos do projeto (incluindo os arquivos do composer) para o servidor via ftp.

Comment: Teoricamente, se você subiu para o servidor toda a pasta `vendor` e está devidamente incluindo o arquivo de `autoload.php`, deveria funcionar, a mesmo que a hospedagem bloqueie algo.

Comment: O seu erro me parece um problema de configuração no php.ini. Você consegue confirmar se o módulo do mysql_pdo está carregado? Você pode verificar se está carregado com o seguinte código: `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());`

Comment: @jlHertel esse código retorna o seguite valor : `Array ( [0] => sqlite )`

Comment: @kyro23, neste caso a extensão do mysql para PDO não está carregada no servidor. Você tem acesso ao php.ini para habilitar ela?

Comment: @jlHertel consegui resolver, tive que pedir pro pessoal do suporte do servidor ativar essa opção pra mim. Era isso mesmo! Obrigado.